# Ubuntu 13.04 Adding Extra Clicks. Loose Grip When Dragging

Tags: 13.04, mouse

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and notice that my mouse is behaving weirdly. If I try to drag a selected text, folders or files, sometimes the selection will loose. If I make one click, sometimes, it will add two clicks. It happens in both my Laptop and the Desktop machines. Two different mouse. How can we fix this?

Comment: did you tweak something, like double-click speed or something?  How is the test result in your `mouse & touchpad test result?

Comment: I tried to reduce the double click speed. But it didn't help. Even reformatted the system

Comment: I can confirm this problem. I thought it was my mouse but I tried 3 more and same problem. In my case and I suspect EApubs case, I did not change anything at all related to mouse settings. Not even sensibility. The problem can be reproduce faster if you open Nautilus and select several files or folders with the intention of copying them, then immediately after selecting them, right click for the context menu to appear. When the context menu appears, you will loose the selected objects. This only happens the first time.

Comment: I have the same problem in both 12.10 and to a lesser extent in 13.04 on my brand new laptop. I sense it might have to do with the sensitivity slider in the mouse/trackpad configurations.

Comment: @EApubs: '...happens in both my Laptop and the Desktop machines.' Including the laptop's touchpad?

Comment: @AryoAdhi I think there's no issue with the touch pad. But I don't use it much

Comment: can you make sure the mouse "receiver" is plugged in to the computer directly and not a hub. Then if that doesn't work try a wired mouse. We need to rule out hardware level interference. Linux, with one of my old laptops, used the wireless card in such a way as to damage bluetooth in the immediate area.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado I'm having this problem. I tried replacing mouse but didn't help. Possible bug?

Comment: @EApubs A bug report was created see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened me all the time since I started to use computers as daily basis. What is happening, most likely, is that your mouse (both) are getting old, the push button inside is getting weaker because of extensive use, ending in multiple clicks.

All you can do is getting a new mouse, in fact I'm about to get one because the same reason.

EDIT:

As it is likely to be a hardware problem with the mouse itself. Found this instructable  to repair this issue. [Repair-mouse-with-double-click-problem](http://www.instructables.com/id/Repair-mouse-with-double-click-problem/step7/locate-remove-and-retension-the-spring/)

EDIT2:

You could also try to change the "Double-Click Timeout" to "Short" in "Mouse and Touchpad" Settings

Comment: The mouse I use in my PC is brand new. Bought in January. The other mouse is several years old. But the problem comes in both of them. In two different machines! But its not there in Windows. I didn't even faced it in Ubuntu 12.10. Only in 13.04!

Comment: "You could also try to change the "Double-Click Timeout" to "Short"" fast maybe?

Comment: @AryoAdhi Tried that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

A bug report was created since it affects several users: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1181272